# How to move main thread forward after the background thread finishes it's work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am making a network call and fetching the topology as soon as user launch the app. 
Here is the catch, to fetch the topology first I need few of the values from other app's content provider, Every other answer, blogs on the internet says that the querying to ContentProvider should happen in the background thread; which make sense for me as well. But if i make background thread and make query to CP, my app's main thread will start executing before I get the values from CP. How to tackle this scenario?

So far I tried AsyncTask and showed Progress Dialog in preExecute() and dismiss it on postExecute() but then also it has no use for my scenario.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // building URI for content resolver
        //contentURI = new Uri.Builder().build().parse(contentPath);
        progressDialog.setMessage("calling ContentProvider");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        if(!SplashActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "calling ContentProvider ");
        Log.d(TAG, "calling @ ===> " + contentURI);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        try{
            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);

        if (null == cursor) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ContentProvider returned null response.");
        } else if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ContentProvider returned empty response.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ContentProvider returned Data Successfully.");
            mContentProviderData = cursor;
            int rawReturned = cursor.getCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of raws returned into CP: " + String.valueOf(rawReturned));
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Please attach relevant code samples, as well as detail what fixes you have tried already. It would be worthwhile to review this stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions. As it stands it will be very difficult for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Use a `ContentObserver` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver

Comment: @ElliWhite I have added the asyncTask I have tried with progress dialog.

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks for your reply. I know it will be a observer pattern and I will take a look. but will it catch the data before my main thread starts executing further?

Comment: Why not put your main thread logic inside the `onPostExecute`? And show a loading animation while the data is being fetched.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "So far I tried AsyncTask and showed Progress Dialog in preExecute() and dismiss it on postExecute() but then also it has no use for my scenario." @Ddp, can you elaborate why this does not work for your use case?

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz yes this can be useful.